# Disposing Of An Instance from Activator.CreateInstance()

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have software with a plugin system that loads DLL's using Assembly.Load() + Activator.CreateInstance(). The issue that I am having is the fact that the plugin keeps the process open, for example if I close the main window the process still remains open in the background and does not close properly.

My question is, is it possible to remove/unload an instance created by Activator.CreateInstance()? I tried setting the object to null and calling GC.Collect() as suggested in another question, but this was to no avail...

```
 async public void AddServerModule(Assembly module)
 {
    Type type = module.GetType("ModularModule.ModularModule");
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { this });
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Is it `IDisposable` then you can use a `using` block, if not why not?

Comment: Are you suggesting to make the plug-ins use IDisposable?

Comment: `if(instance is IDisposable d) d.Dispose();` (+ exception handling etc). Otherwise, force `type` to implement some interface, which extends `IDisposable`.

Comment: I've never heard of a Loaded assembly _keeping the process running_. When that's happened to me it's because I started a thread up, didn't mark it as a background thread and left it running. Is there anything particularly funky about this assembly?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman That worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by making the plugin disposable, then calling Close() in the Dispose() method.

Comment: I'd advise to use a `using` block instead, this will deal with exceptions properly